# Building AOSP and adding a system app with runtime permission

Tags: android, apk, android-source

I work on Android 6 AOSP. I am able to build add the application as a system app
but now I want to add runtime permission by default on this system app. Like that the app can start without asking the user to validate the permission.

Do you know how I can do that?

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 7):

If your app is privileged, all Runtime permissions are granted if requested in manifest.

To make your app privileged:
in Android.mk

```
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform
LOCAL_PRIVILEGED_MODULE := true
```

If this does not solve your problem:
1. You can grant Runtime permissions to your app in Runtime. App must have android.Manifest.permission.GRANT_RUNTIME_PERMISSIONS.  [Pm.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/cmds/pm/src/com/android/commands/pm/Pm.java)

```
IPackageManager pm = IPackageManager.Stub.asInterface(ServiceManager.getService("package"));
pm.grantRuntimePermission(pkgname, perm, UserHandle.USER_OWNER);
pm.updatePermissionFlags(perm, pkgname, PackageManager.FLAG_PERMISSION_GRANTED_BY_DEFAULT,
PackageManager.FLAG_PERMISSION_GRANTED_BY_DEFAULT, UserHandle.USER_OWNER);
```

2. You can grant permissions manually by modifying 
   [DefaultPermissionGrantPolicy.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/services/core/java/com/android/server/pm/DefaultPermissionGrantPolicy.java).

Additionally, if app use shared user id with system. Any permission is granted even though it is not requested in manifest.

```
android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system".
```

Answer (score 1):

You can grant runtime permissions to system apps by modifying the `DefaultPermissionsGrantPolicy.java` class.

In the `grantDefaultSystemHandlerPermissions(int userId)` method, add this code:

```
PackageParser.Package yourPackage = getSystemPackageLPr("YOUR_APP_PACKAGE_NAME");
if (yourPackage != null
                && doesPackageSupportRuntimePermissions(yourPackage)) {
    grantRuntimePermissionsLPw(yourPackage, CONTACTS_PERMISSIONS, userId);
    grantRuntimePermissionsLPw(yourPackage, CALENDAR_PERMISSIONS, userId);
}
```

Make sure you add the code above this line:

`mService.mSettings.onDefaultRuntimePermissionsGrantedLPr(userId);`