# Android runtime permissions for System app

Tags: android, android-permissions

I'm building an android app and made it as system app by placing it under /system/priv-app (building AOSP)
Android OS version : 6.0.1 (api 23)

```
ApplicationInfo ai = packageManager.getApplicationInfo(
                    packageName, 0);
            // Check if FLAG_SYSTEM or FLAG_UPDATED_SYSTEM_APP are set.
            if (ai != null
                    && (ai.flags & (ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM | ApplicationInfo.FLAG_UPDATED_SYSTEM_APP)) != 0) {
                return true;
            }
```

This code retuns true (for system app)

I've read that system apps will have all the runtime permissions like location, storage, etc.

But it is still asking for permissions (system dialog) for location and storage.

**What i've tried ?**

1) used this permission in manifest `"android.Manifest.permission.GRANT_RUNTIME_PERMISSIONS"`

2) added few lines of code in framework

```
   services/core/java/com/android/server/pm/DefaultPermissionGrantPolicy.java
```

as mentioned [here](https://github.com/ProjectDisco/android_frameworks_base/commit/da1408d4a3df46af11854bf68844be133c5a20d3#diff-b748b21a02a7dfa1cccd67d1a5b06dec)

but still app is asking for permissions.

note* : i'm also looking to get permissions for `android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS`,  `WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS` and `Draw over other apps` without asking/prompting the user

***One more note* :***

**This app is for a custom hardware with custom OS, i have access to all of framework code**

Comment: I may be wrong but I don't think you can bypass the permissions dialog. I am doing something similar and I thought that you wouldn't need to ask for them too. But the draw over apps perm does not need a user prompt.

Comment: @Regulus "But the draw over apps perm does not need a user prompt" is that for system apps?

Comment: Yes, I am referring to system apps. Of course, assuming you have set the appropriate permissions, such as SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW.

Comment: @Regulus Ok, so basically it is not possible to avoid permission dialog on API 23 and above. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, dump your package service and inspect the package has correct flag and permissions. If your app is privileged, privateFlags must have  **PRIVILEGED**. If your app is privileged, all Runtime permissions are granted if it is requested in the manifest. However I'm not sure this is true on Android 6.0.

```
adb shell dumpsys package

Packages:
  Package [com.android.systemui] (4dfb5a):
....
  flags=[ SYSTEM HAS_CODE PERSISTENT ]
  privateFlags=[ PRIVILEGED DEFAULT_TO_DEVICE_PROTECTED_STORAGE DIRECT_BOOT_AWARE RESIZEABLE_ACTIVITIES ]
  dataDir=/data/user_de/0/com.android.systemui
....
  pkgFlags=[ SYSTEM HAS_CODE PERSISTENT ]
  declared permissions:
    com.android.systemui.permission.SELF: prot=signature, INSTALLED
  requested permissions:
    android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED
    android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
....
  install permissions:
    android.permission.REAL_GET_TASKS: granted=true
    android.permission.REMOTE_AUDIO_PLAYBACK: granted=true
```

And please have a look this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48743350/building-aosp-and-adding-a-system-app-with-runtime-permission/48743935#48743935)